# How is India's technology transfer policy different from China's?

Tags: china, india, technology

> The Indian government has played a vital role in the Quiet Revolution
> by establishing favourable policies, investing in R&D, and negotiating
> technology transfer agreements with foreign nations and companies.
> Private companies and research institutions have also contributed
> through partnerships with international organizations and taking
> advantage of technological opportunities. International partners such
> as foreign governments and companies have been crucial in bringing
> technology to India through investment and collaboration.

https://tfipost.com/2023/02/the-quiet-revolution-indias-diplomatic-success-in-bringing-tech-transfer/

How is India's technology transfer policy different from China's? It seems that India is negotiating and I've read that China is "forcing" technology transfer by forcing Western companies by doing joint ventures, but can someone give me an extensive comparison between the policies of the two nations, considering they're both rising economic superpowers?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145707/discussion-on-question-by-sayaman-how-is-indias-technology-transfer-policy-diff); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What you quoted is how India/ the Indian government sees this policy. At least so far the Western companies don't feel threatened by Indias technological achievements, they do feel threatened by the Chinese.